# Using reflection to find an enumerator's method

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, enumerator, ienumerator

**Background:**

I am modifying existing code using the [Harmony Library](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony).  The existing C# code follows this structure:

```
public class ToModify
{
    public override void Update()
    {
        foreach (StatusItemGroup.Entry entry in collection)
        {
            // I am trying to alter an operation at the end of this loop.
        }
    }
}

public class StatusItemGroup
{
    public IEnumerator<Entry> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private List<Entry> items = new List<Entry>();

    public struct Entry { }
}
```

Due to the situation, I must modify the IL code that is being generated, to do so I must obtain the `MethodInfo` of my target operand.  This is the target:

```
IL_12B6: callvirt  instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
```

**Question:**

How do I obtain the `MethodInfo` for the `MoveNext` method of an enumerator?

**What I've tried:**

Everything I can think of has yielded `null` results.  This is my most basic attempt:

```
MethodInfo targetMethod = typeof(IEnumerator<StatusItemGroup.Entry>).GetMethod("MoveNext");
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, and I don't know what I need to do to correctly obtain the `MethodInfo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MoveNext` is not defined on `IEnumerator<T>`, but on the non-generic `IEnumerator` which is inherited by `IEnumerator<T>`.

Interface inheritance is a little weird in combination with reflection, so you need to obtain the method info directly from the base interface where it's defined:

```
MethodInfo targetMethod = typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext");
```

Comment: Did you mean `MethodInfo targetMethod = typeof(IEnumerator<>).GetMethod("MoveNext");`?  As you've written it I get the following error: `Using the generic type 'IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments`.  However as I've written it, it still returns null.

Comment: @Aze Did you try to copy/paste the code from this answer? kalimag is explicit speaking of the **non-generic** IEnumerator

Comment: @SirRufo Ah, I now realize that `IEnumerator` requires `using System.Collections`.  Thank you.

Comment: @Aze It is always a wise choice to have a look at the docs ;o)

Comment: @Aze Personally I love the [IntelliSenseExtender](https://github.com/Dreamescaper/IntelliSenseExtender) extension in VS

Answer (score 1):

Using the free LinqPad, I create this with Harmony 2.0 RC2. As you can see did I use a pass-through postfix to change the enumerator and wrap it. There are other ways and I suspect that you actually have an IEnumeration somewhere instead. That would be way easier to patch by using the pass-through postfix directly on the original method that returns the IEnumeration. No need to wrap the enumerator in that case.

But I don't know your full use case, so for now, this is the working example:

```cs
void Main()
{
    var harmony = new Harmony("test");
    harmony.PatchAll();

    var group = new StatusItemGroup();
    var items = new List<StatusItemGroup.Entry>() { StatusItemGroup.Entry.Make("A"), StatusItemGroup.Entry.Make("B") };
    Traverse.Create(group).Field("items").SetValue(items);

    var enumerator = group.GetEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.id);
}

[HarmonyPatch]
class Patch
{
    public class ProxyEnumerator<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
        public Func<T, T> transformer;
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            while(enumerator.MoveNext())
                yield return transformer(enumerator.Current);
        }
    } 

    [HarmonyPatch(typeof(StatusItemGroup), "GetEnumerator")]
    static IEnumerator<StatusItemGroup.Entry> Postfix(IEnumerator<StatusItemGroup.Entry> enumerator)
    {
        StatusItemGroup.Entry Transform(StatusItemGroup.Entry entry)
        {
            entry.id += "+";
            return entry;
        }

        var myEnumerator = new ProxyEnumerator<StatusItemGroup.Entry>()
        {
            enumerator = enumerator,
            transformer = Transform
        };
        return myEnumerator.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public class StatusItemGroup
{
    public IEnumerator<Entry> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private List<Entry> items = new List<Entry>();

    public struct Entry
    {
        public string id;
        public static Entry Make(string id) { return new Entry() { id = id }; }
    }
}
```